# Exception thrown in jax-rs ResponseFilter doesn't cause rollback

Tags: java, transactions, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm stuggling with auto-rollback of a container managed transaction. I understand that when throwing an exception, this should happen automatically, but somehow, this isn't happening.

To be clear, I have a JAX-RS `ContainerResponseFilter` which throws some kind of RuntimeException (I can't throw a checked exception btw, as that would mean I need to specify "throws", which can't be done on an implementing method).

When I call `sessionContext.setRollbackOnly()` myself, the transaction is rolled back indeed, but I don't really want to handle it myself.

I tried marking the exception as `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` but that doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?
This is on JBOSS 7.2 with RestEasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been unable to confirm this is intended behaviour, but any manual rollback within the `ContainerReponseFilter` is just too late, as the transaction was committed already.

To resolve the problem, I've reworked my solution to throw the exception from within an `Ìntegercepter` with `@AroundInvoke` . This appears to be in time for the auto-rollback, and allows me to avoid throwing further exceptions in the `ContainerResponseFilter`